# In oracle sql queries - Is it valid to use % in between a search string

Tags: oracle

For example

```
select * from tbl where msg like ‘%\<CDT\>5000%\<DBT\>1000%’
```

msg: <TXN1><CDT>5000<\CDT><\TXN1><something else><TXN2><DBT>1000<\DBT><\TXN2>

I am looking to extract column values, if it has CDT as 5000 and DBT as 1000

Comment: Missed the XML tags in search string and Text to search

Answer (score 0):

Title question is:

> is it valid to use % in between a search string, for example
> `where msg like ‘%5000%1000%’`

Yes, it is valid.

---

What would CDT and DBT be? Extract *which* column values?

Comment: Updated the post to include CDT and DBT XML tags

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure but I think what you want is to take the value of everything between  and 
The following code does that

```
with raw_text(t) as( select '<TXN1><CDT>5000</CDT></TXN1>' from dual)
SELECT *
                    FROM raw_text
                         CROSS JOIN
                         XMLTABLE (
                             '//CDT'
                             PASSING XMLTYPE (raw_text.t)
                             COLUMNS CDT    VARCHAR2 (1000) PATH './text()')
```

Answer (score 0):

Lets assume that you have valid XML data (a single root element, matching opening and closing tags and using `/`, and not \, for the closing tags). For example:

```sql
CREATE TABLE tbl (id, msg) AS
SELECT 1, '<ROOT><TXN1><CDT>5000</CDT></TXN1><something /><TXN2><DBT>1000</DBT></TXN2></ROOT>' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 2, '<ROOT><TXN1><CDT>50000</CDT></TXN1><something /><TXN2><DBT>1000</DBT></TXN2></ROOT>' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 3, '<ROOT><TXN1><CDT>5000</CDT></TXN1><something /><TXN2><DBT>10000</DBT></TXN2></ROOT>' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 4, '<ROOT><TXN2><DBT>1000</DBT></TXN2><TXN1><CDT>5000</CDT></TXN1><something /></ROOT>' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 5, '<ROOT><TXN1><CDT note="match me too">5000</CDT></TXN1><something /><TXN2><DBT>1000</DBT></TXN2></ROOT>' FROM DUAL;
```

Where `id`s 1, 4 and 5 all have values `5000` and `1000` but `id` 4 has the order of the transactions reversed in the XML (which is completely valid XML and does not change the data at all) and `id` 5 is the same as `id` 1 but with an added attribute on the `CDT` element. `id`s 2 has `CDT` of `50000` instead of `5000` and 3 has `DBT` of `10000` instead of `1000`.

Then, yes, you could use:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM   tbl
WHERE  msg LIKE '%<CDT>5000%<DBT>1000%'
```

But it would return rows 1, 2 and 3 and would not match row 4 or 5. This is probably not what you want.

You could eliminate rows 2 and 3 by matching the end tags  as well:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM   tbl
WHERE  msg LIKE '%<CDT>5000</CDT>%<DBT>1000</DBT>%'
```

But that still does not match when the tags are reversed or when there are additional attributes.

---

If you want to match the values then you can use `XMLEXISTS`:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM   tbl
WHERE  XMLEXISTS('//CDT[text()=5000]' PASSING XMLTYPE(msg))
AND    XMLEXISTS('//DBT[text()=1000]' PASSING XMLTYPE(msg))
```

Which outputs:

> | ID | MSG |
> | --- | --- |
> | 1 | <ROOT><TXN1><CDT>5000</CDT></TXN1><something /><TXN2><DBT>1000</DBT></TXN2></ROOT> |
> | 4 | <ROOT><TXN2><DBT>1000</DBT></TXN2><TXN1><CDT>5000</CDT></TXN1><something /></ROOT> |
> | 5 | <ROOT><TXN1><CDT note="match me too">5000</CDT></TXN1><something /><TXN2><DBT>1000</DBT></TXN2></ROOT> |

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=bcdd201dd88d3350bf2679a1fd201038)*